# How to create a bent gradient?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm programming snake with Javascript. For the background of the different body parts I'm using the following gradient generation:

```
gibGradient: function() {
    var string = "background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(243,226,199,1) 15%,rgba(193,158,103,1) "+ snake.data.gradientLinks +"%,rgba(182,141,76,1) "+ snake.data.gradientRechts +"%,rgba(233,212,179,1) 90%);";
    if ((snake.data.gradientLinks < 85) && (snake.data.modus == "hochzaehlen")) {
        snake.data.gradientLinks = snake.data.gradientLinks + 5;
        snake.data.gradientRechts = snake.data.gradientRechts + 5;
        if (snake.data.gradientLinks >= 85) {
            snake.data.modus = "runterZaehlen";
        }
    }

    if ((snake.data.gradientLinks > 20) && (snake.data.modus == "runterZaehlen")) {
        snake.data.gradientLinks = snake.data.gradientLinks - 5;
        snake.data.gradientRechts = snake.data.gradientRechts - 5;
        if (snake.data.gradientLinks <= 20) {
            snake.data.modus = "hochzaehlen";
        }
    }
    return string;
},
```

My problem is that when the snake moves and it changes directions, the gradient needs to be bent to fit in the last body part before the corner ends and the last that follows the straight of the snake.

For Example:

Im using 10x10 px div elements

[image: Example]

Now i need the transition when it moves a corner

Anybody got an idea?

Comment: In which direction is the gradient, perpendicular or parallel to the longitudinal axis of your snake? An image would help. Maybe a simple `radial-gradient` can solve your problem.

Comment: can you provide a picture of what you mean

Comment: are you using canvas or other elements?

Comment: you can resort to radial gradients for corners https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient you can set the size then offset depending on which corner

Comment: you can use [border-radius](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius)

Comment: you can rotate your gradient by including a degree `linear-gradient(45deg, red, blue);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I took the time to write a few utility javascript functions you may find useful. They require the use of the jQuery library however. The best way to create bent gradients is to use offset radial gradients. This combined with border radius makes for a really nice effect.

Now it is up to you to

- use the right function at the right times (the naming convention of
  the functions is sideA_To_sideB so rightToUp means going right will
  eventually find sideA and going up will eventually find sideB - sides
  being the head or the tail)
- make it cross browser (if you are into that sort of thing)
- rounding the head and tail would be a nice touch (ideally this rounding would only occur on 
  vertical and horizontal parts)

Feel free to change the size variable to suit your needs.

**EDIT** - based on the image you just added I created this : jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lbydhhkh/. This was done using rotated linear gradients. I still think using my original approach looks better and makes more sense. This should be enough to send you in the right direction though. The pseudocode can still be used for this new code.

```js
var size = 40;

function aToB(gradient) {
    return $("<div>").css({
        width: size,
        height: size,
        background: gradient,
        position: "absolute"
    });
}

function radialOut(x, y, corner) {
    var css = {};
    css["border-" + corner + "-radius"] = size / 2;
    return aToB([
        "radial-gradient(",
    size,
        "px at ",
    x,
        "px ",
    y,
        "px, red, blue)"].join("")).css(css);
}

function radialIn(x, y, corner) {
    var css = {};
    css["border-" + corner + "-radius"] = size / 2;
    return aToB([
        "radial-gradient(",
    size,
        "px at ",
    x,
        "px ",
    y,
        "px, blue, red)"].join("")).css(css);
}

function downToUp() {
    return aToB("linear-gradient(to left, red, blue)");
}

function rightToLeft() {
    return aToB("linear-gradient(to bottom, red, blue)");
}

function upToDown() {
    return aToB("linear-gradient(to right, red, blue)");
}

function leftToRight() {
    return aToB("linear-gradient(to top, red, blue)");
}

function upToRight() {
    return radialIn(size, 0, "bottom-left");
}

function leftToUp() {
    return radialIn(0, 0, "bottom-right");
}

function downToLeft() {
    return radialIn(0, size, "top-right");
}

function rightToDown() {
    return radialIn(size, size, "top-left");
}

function rightToUp() {
    return radialOut(size, 0, "bottom-left");
}

function upToLeft() {
    return radialOut(0, 0, "bottom-right");
}

function leftToDown() {
    return radialOut(0, size, "top-right");
}

function downToRight() {
    return radialOut(size, size, "top-left");
}

$(function () {
    //inner
    $("body").append(upToDown().css({
        top: size,
        left: 0
    })).append(upToRight().css({
        top: size * 2,
        left: 0
    })).append(leftToRight().css({
        top: size * 2,
        left: size
    })).append(leftToUp().css({
        top: size * 2,
        left: size * 2
    })).append(downToUp().css({
        top: size,
        left: size * 2
    })).append(downToLeft().css({
        top: 0,
        left: size * 2
    })).append(rightToLeft().css({
        top: 0,
        left: size
    })).append(rightToDown().css({
        top: 0,
        left: 0
    }));

    //outer
    $("body").append(leftToDown().css({
        top: 0,
        left: size * 5
    })).append(upToDown().css({
        top: size,
        left: size * 5
    })).append(upToLeft().css({
        top: size * 2,
        left: size * 5
    })).append(rightToLeft().css({
        top: size * 2,
        left: size * 4
    })).append(rightToUp().css({
        top: size * 2,
        left: size * 3
    })).append(downToUp().css({
        top: size * 1,
        left: size * 3
    })).append(downToRight().css({
        top: 0,
        left: size * 3
    })).append(leftToRight().css({
        top: 0,
        left: size * 4
    }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also here is some pseudocode to help you call the appropriate functions

```
while(nextPart()) { //while there are more parts to process
    var prev = getPrev(), //returns null or previous part
        curr = getCurrent(), //returns current part
        next = getNext(), //returns null or next part
        a, b, part = [];

    //get the direction towards the tail
    if(prev) a = curr.getDirectionTo(prev); //returns "up", "right", "down", or "left"
    else a = tail.getOppositeDirection(); //returns "up", "right", "down", or "left"

    //get the direction towards the head
    if(next) b = curr.getDirectionTo(next);
    else b = head.getDirection(); //returns "up", "right", "down", or "left"

    b = upperCaseFirstLetter(b);

    if(!prev) part.push("tail"); //is this a tail?
    if(!next) part.push("head"); //is this a head?

    //the following line of code calls a function with the form "aToB"
    //the variable part does not do anything yet but it can help the called  
    //function determine if this part is a head, tail, or both for rounding
    var domElement = window[a + "To" + b](part); 
    domElement.css(curr.position()); //properly position the element
    $("#container").append(domElement); //add the element to the container
}
```

Comment: When you say it "doesn't work", do you mean to say it doesn't meet your requirements? Because the code will work in any modern browser that supports css3 gradients

Comment: yeah sorry thats what i ment to say, the code itself works very well but i cant use it without building complete new sneak logic

Comment: i just saw the image you included and updated my answer...i believe i answered the primary question though "How can I create a bent gradient?"

Comment: also when making a game you should have at least 2 loops running, the logic loop and the rendering loop...with the code i provided you do not need new snake logic, you need new snake rendering...if you at least separated these two pipelines you would find game development much easier and more enjoyable